# Can I hide the mnemonics in Qt applications?

Tags: unity, qt

Using stock Ubuntu. The underscores in the menus make these apps (Skype, to a lesser degree VLC etc.) look out of place and (imo) ugly.

Comment: Please post this as a proper answer and mark your question as answered.

Comment: Done. It won't let me mark it though.

Comment: Yes, there usually is a grace period of a few hours before you can mark your own answer. Just remember to come back to mark it when the time comes. Marking questions as answered really helps, both in organizing all of the thousands of questions that come in each day and guiding future users to the right Q&A.

Comment: It says 2 days. But I'll try again later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I actually found the answer. What did it for me was:

```
echo "gtk-enable-mnemonics = 0" > ~/.gtkrc-2.0 && cp ~/.gtkrc-2.0 ~/.gtkrc-3.0
```